# Dynamically hide a row in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to hide 1 row of a `DataGrid` when the user selects something for another row.

How can I do that?

```
 private void DataGridCommands_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridData.Items.Count; i++)
     {
         if ((dataGridData.Items[i] as DataForTable).MsgType ==   _qf.ElementAt(DataGridCommands.SelectedIndex).Mcode)
         {
             //need to hide 1 row from datagriddata
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the logic that you want to use for hidding the row from your datagrid, so I will show you a simple sample.

The point is that you need to retrive the container of the row and hide it. Let's see how. This is the XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
                SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" Name="dataGrid" />
</StackPanel>
```

And now the code-behind:

```
public partial class Window3 : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public Window3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Paul", Surname = "Green" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mike", Surname = "Gray" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Surname = "Black" });

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = people;
    }

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow dataGridRow;
        foreach (Person p in e.AddedItems)
        {
            if (p.Name == "Mike")
            {
                dataGridRow = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(people[2]) as DataGridRow;
                dataGridRow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                return;
            }
        }

        dataGridRow = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(people[2]) as DataGridRow;
        dataGridRow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

My logic is that I want to hide the last person object in my collection if the user select a person named "Mike". So I retrieve the container (a DataGridRow in this case) which correspond to the row I want to hide/show. Then you set its Visibility to the right value.

I hope my sample can give you an hint for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

try following solution

```
public partial class frmTestGirdBinding : Form
{
    CustomDataCollection cdata = new CustomDataCollection();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public frmTestGirdBinding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);
    }

    private void frmTestGirdBinding_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = cdata;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;            

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cdata.Count; i++)
        {
            cdata[i].Reading = (float)rnd.NextDouble();
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh(); //without this all rows are not updating
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        //InVisible the rows
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

another snippet i would like to post

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in taggGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "False")
            {
                dr.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is not a datagrid view this is a datagrid. I am using WPF.

Comment: have you tried 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320528/wpf-hide-row-in-datagrid-based-on-condition

Comment: try it. however it it does not the answer.